# HTML5 Offline Storage - Cache manifest networking

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am trying to write the manifest file but I am having weird problem in FF5, its caching all despite saying to don't do so. My manifest file looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a presentation about offline and local storage not long ago.

Video available here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWCk6FZMpcU

It's a bit complicated. I had to read Dive Into HTML5 multiple times and then experiment a lot to get things working.

I have an example PHP manifest "build" script here: https://github.com/JasonHanley/note5/blob/master/build.php

Answer (score 1):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
this says if you reference the manifest file in html files as manifest attributes then it will be cached even if its not listed in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have anything set to cache, why would you need a cache manifest file if this is the case?  If you are trying to cache some things I would try properly defining them under CACHE: and see if it then cache's the appropriate assets.

Comment: I know, but despite that all is being cached, that is my point